# How do I insert the right path on form creation in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.3

I have this code in my template:

```
<form action="{{ path('wba_create') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        <p>
            <button type="submit">Registrar</button>
        </p>
</form>
```

And in my controller I have this annotation:

```
   /**
     *
     * @Route("/", name="wba_create")
     * @Method("POST")
     */
    public function createAction(Request $request) {
        ....
    }
```

But in the rendered HTML I got just `<form method="post" action="/app_dev.php/">` why? What I miss here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code here ... you're configuring `wba_create` as route `/`

```
@Route("/", name="wba_create")
```

That's the trailing slash in /app_dev.php **/** ... app_dev.php is in the url because you're accessing the page through `app_dev.php` aka in the dev environment.

Comment: so, in order to execute `create` action when form is send what is the right code? I'm a bit lost here

Comment: it is the right code as long as you want your submit url to be `/` ... What is your exact problem? If you submit the form it will be sent to `/` using http method POST. Your controller should receive the request.

Comment: I need to send the form data to `TestController/createAction()` wich will handle the form and save data using entities

Comment: that's exactly what is currently happening with this code. Where are you hanging? Just put a simple `die('hello from testcontroller:create'); into your createAction to check wether the action is actually called ... submit the form and you'll see ... "hello from testcontroller:create" ... or don't you?

Comment: Ohhhh sorry I'm coming from Symfony1 and things change a bit, this is new for me! You're right I get redirected to create. Now if I've a show action defined in my annotation as `@Route("/{id}", name="wba_show")` I can redirect to that function using this `$this->redirect($this->generateUrl('wba_show', array('id' => $entity->getTypeId())));`?

Comment: you got it - maybe add a default id or some requirement like d+ to your route annotation but that's basically it ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you're running your Symfony application in development mode, every page is being treated by app_dev.php (including the page where your form is shown)

Your code should work, don't worry about the /app_dev.php/ added to the URL, it will not be there if you use the production environment.